# probelm with reverse.c in CS50, audio file sounds reversed but check50 produces error

Tags: c, reverse, cs50

I am doing a CS50 exercise where I am tasked on reversing an audio file using purely C code. I have my code pasted in below.

My code is producing the reversed audio, but the final test case is not passing. Can someone please tell me why this is not passing?

Code:

```
// includes and function protos

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Ensure proper usage
    if(argc != 3)
    {
        printf("Usage ./reverse input.wav output.wav");
        return 1;
    }

    // Open input file for reading
    FILE *inptr = fopen(argv[1],"r");
    if(inptr==NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open %s",argv[1]);
        return 2;
    }

    // Read header
    WAVHEADER *header = malloc(sizeof(WAVHEADER));
    fread(header,HEADER_SIZE,1,inptr);

    // Use check_format to ensure WAV format
    if(check_format(*header)==0)
    {
        printf("%s is not a WAV file",argv[1]);
        return 3;
    }

    // Open output file for writing
    FILE *outptr = fopen(argv[2],"w");

    // Write header to file
    fwrite(header,HEADER_SIZE,1,outptr);

    // Use get_block_size to calculate size of block
    int BLOCK_SIZE = get_block_size(*header);

    // Write reversed audio to file
    int *buffer = malloc(BLOCK_SIZE);
    fseek(inptr,0,SEEK_END);
    int SAMPLE_NO = (ftell(inptr)-HEADER_SIZE)/BLOCK_SIZE;
    for(int i = 0;i<SAMPLE_NO;i++)
    {
        if(i==0)
        {
            fseek(inptr,-1*BLOCK_SIZE,SEEK_CUR);
        }
        else
        {
            fseek(inptr,-2*BLOCK_SIZE,SEEK_CUR);
        }
        fread(buffer,BLOCK_SIZE,1,inptr);
        fwrite(buffer,BLOCK_SIZE,1,outptr);
    }
    
    // Close file..
}

int check_format(WAVHEADER header)
{
    if(header.format[0]== 0x57 && header.format[1]== 0x41 && header.format[2]== 0x56 && header.format[3]== 0x45)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }

}

// Get block size function...
```

Please note that some code is abbreviated due to stackoverflow limitations

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please do not try to circumvent quality checks by adding garbage characters instead of useful text. Cheating the system is not increasing the willingness to help.